# Talend - tFileInputRegex

Tags: regex, talend

My goal is to parse several text files using a RegEx, and based on match to copy file renaming it (including regex match string in the file name itself):

Talend project overview using tFileInputRegex:
[image: Talend project overview]

Regex should find all rows matching "Invoice - xxxxx" or "Num.Ord - yyyyy".

So I can have files like this (Invoice    -  10044165 RI):

```
     Company XXX, LLC                                          Page Number-            1
 P.O. Box 26610                                        I N V O I C E                      Date       -     02/15/05
 Miami, MI  64196                                                                         Customer   -        20035
                                                                          Lot Potency.     50006427
                                                                                          Brn/Plt    -    100780000
                                              REMIT TO:                                   Order Nbr  -    242242 SO
                                                            .                             Invoice    -  10044165 RI
```

Or like this (Num.Ord    -     50006427):

```
     Company XXX, LLC                                          Page Number-            1
 P.O. Box 26610                                        I N V O I C E                      Date       -     02/15/05
 Miami, MI  64196                                                                         Customer   -        20035
                                                                          Num.Ord    -     50006427
                                                                                          Brn/Plt    -    100780000
                                              REMIT TO:                                  
                                                            .                         
                                              126 Ctest
                                              Chicago, IL
```

I'm trying to figure it out how to have a working OR Regex searching for rows containing "Num.Ord" OR "Invoice".
I've tested online with a regex parser and this one works:

```
[\n\r].*(Invoice|Num.Ord)\s*-\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

When I try to import in Talend component `tFileInputRegex`, using appropriate notation, it does not work (no match on OR "Num.Ord"):

```
"[\\n\\r].*(Invoice|Num.Ord)\\s*-\\s*([^\\n\\r]*)"
```

Comment: Your regex seems needlessly complex. Doesn't [`.*(?:Invoice|Num\\.Ord).*`](https://regex101.com/r/UnEsA0/3) work for you? Edit : edited to include whole lines rather than just the relevant part

Comment: Maybe a DOTALL is necessary, try `(?s).*(Num\\.Ord|Invoice)\\s*-\\s*([^\n\r]+).*`

Comment: Hi, thx but on Talend are not working in both way! I cannot understand why if I try online (regex.com) this regx "([\n\r]).*(Num\.Ord|Invoice)\s*-\s*([^\n\r]+).*" and this one "[\n\r].*Invoice\s*-\s*([^\n\r]*)" produce same output, that actually is my goal. Am I'm missing something to be setted on Talend? thx

Comment: screenshot about online regex test: https://snag.gy/JL7yuK.jpg and https://snag.gy/Z59WRD.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've sorted out by parsing again with another tFileInputRegex Talend component with files rejected by first one:

Talend job schema:
[image: Talend job schema]